# Display 2 different query results in table with Kibana

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, kibana, rsyslog

I'm trying to show logs from 2 different servers in Kibana. 
Here's picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgCq.png

In first table I'd like to show logs about Server 1 and in table 2( on the right) logs from another Server.

Is this even possible with Kibana? If I write query, both tables data change.

I'm using Kibana 3.1, because I didin't find table function for Kibana 4
Elasticsearch 1.4.4
Rsyslog for sending logs to Elasticsearch

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the configure icon on each of the panels (the cog icon) and click the Queries option. In the queries dropdown click selected and select the queries you want to provide data for the particular panel.